# Is it possible to take screenshot in unrooted android phone.?

Tags: android, screenshot

I am developing an application in which there is a button on click of that button i want the screenshot of android screen not that application screen my phone is unrooted. Is it possible to take screenshot of unrooted phone.?

Comment: similar ques http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android

Answer (score 3):

## Yes it is possible.

have a look at [**Android Screenshot Library**](https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/).

> Android Screenshot Library (ASL) enables to programmatically capture screenshots from Android devices without requirement of having root access privileges. Instead, ASL utilizes a native service running in the background, started via the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) once per device boot.

## How to Implement?

**Modifying the manifest XML**

In order for Android service to be accessible, add the following declaration to your client application's XML manifest:

```
<service android:name="pl.polidea.asl.ScreenshotService">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="pl.polidea.asl.ScreenshotService.BIND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**Binding service**

To obtain the IScreenshotProvider interface one must bind to the ASL service (pl.polidea.asl.ScreenshotService) using Context.bindService - for example:

```
// (using class name)
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass (this, pl.polidea.asl.ScreenshotService.class);
bindService (intent, aslServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

**References**

- https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/wiki/DeveloperGuide
- https://github.com/rtyley/android-screenshot-lib

Comment: How to use this library in android studio ?

Comment: It has java project. so you can build that with Android studio